# Why is my npx create-react-app ./ not working?

Tags: reactjs, terminal, npx

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to folder C:\Program Files\nodejs
2. You have to edit four files named npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd
3. Open the files in a text editor, like Visual Studio Code
4. Replace prefix -g with prefix --location=global in all four files
5. Save all (if asked, save as administrator)

Comment: It is still not working.  npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'